# Getting last indexed Text in Array [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to get last text which containing something in an array. And return it to number.

```
var MalArray:Array = new Array();
MalArray = [mal11.text, mal22.text, mal33.text, mal44.text,mal55.text, mal66.text, mal77.text, mal88.text, mal99.text, mal1010.text];
```

For example:

```
mal11.text="asd"
mal22.text="ddd"
mal33.text="eee"
mal44.text=""
mal55.text=""...
```

The Number should be = 3

Comment: Hi, try my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var MalArray:Array = new Array();

MalArray = [mal11.text, mal22.text, mal33.text, mal44.text,mal55.text, mal66.text,   mal77.text, mal88.text, mal99.text, mal1010.text];

var last:int = -1;
for(var i:int = 0; i<MalArray.length; i++) {

if(MalArray[i] == "")
  {
      var answer = MalArray[i-1];
      trace("answer is "+answer + " "+(i-1));
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(EDITED after comment)

```
var last:int = -1;
for(var i:int; i<MalArray.length; i++) {
    var curr:String = MalArray[i];
    if (curr != "") {
        last = i;
    }
}
```

In the `last` variable you store the last element of array with text valued.

Comment: it doesnt work. in output ReferenceError: Error #1069:text cannt be found on string